# Environment variable created inside .env file is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

The `.env` file looks like this:

```
# .env
MY_SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD = 'secret'
```

In the file I want to import it:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const pass = process.env.MY_SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD;
```

the problem is that `pass` is **undefined**. What is wrong?

Comment: Where is your .env file located at?

Comment: right inside the project's folder. at the same level with src, node_modules, etc. the file where I want to import it is inside src

Comment: Try removing  single quote, MY_SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD = secret

Comment: I tried, still undefined

Comment: I don`t think you are making any mistake because I am currently working on node.js project and I have used env variables exactly as you have used. Mine is working perfectly fine.

Comment: That's the weird thing. Everything seems fine but something isn't.

Comment: check where you are calling this dotenv.config(), try requiring and calling this at upper scope before using process.env

Answer (score 0):

```
const path = require('path');
// path to your .env file
const loadPath = path.join(__dirname, './.env');
// Local config loader
require('dotenv').config({ silent: false, path: loadPath });
```

@Leo could you try to use the above solution, it seems you need to add the config file path explicitly.also no need to use the single quotes.